# “Infamous” used in a positive sense?

Tags: meaning

I have found at least twice the adjective “infamous” used, apparently, to mean “very famous”, rather than its actual, opposite meaning, both times in non-humorous texts:

The first, a historical essay about ancient Spartan lawgiver Lycurgus:

> At some point between the late eighth and mid-seventh century BC ... a new constitution came into force in Sparta; known as the Great Rhetra, this constitution was, by the fifth century BC, associated directly with Sparta's **infamous lawgiver Lycurgus**...

And the second, a popular science article about the Goodyear blimp:

> 3 June 1925: The **infamous Goodyear blimp** first flies. These would go on to be a regular part of sporting events in the US.

Is this a new use of the term? Or were those most likely plain oversights?

If it matters, both texts are by British authors.

UPDATE: A recent (mis)use of “infamous” to just say “very famous”: https://www.fallacyfiles.org/archive092023.html#09042023

Comment: Can you quote the actual two passages, so we can analyze it from sources?

Comment: Ok, I just checked [literally 29 dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=infamous&ls=a) and they're all in agreement *infamous* means of wide, *ill*, repute, aka *notorious*. The only glimmer of hope I can see for your two authors (assuming you're reading them right) is [TFD records a definition of infamy](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=infamous) as "*known widely and **usually** unfavorably*". But that's a weak hope indeed.

Comment: You're right about the sources: I'm going to insert them right now.

Comment: I think a case could be made that Lycurgus was actually infamous, for example, from Wikipedia: "*[Lycurgus] was also credited with the development of the agoge. **The infamous practice** took all healthy seven-year-old boys from the care of their fathers and placed them in a rigorous military regiment*". Anyway, for generals and warmongers and other macho men, *infamous* is often used as a term of approbation. What's better for a macho man than being *famously bad*? You think Genghis Khan would balk at the label? I tend to agree the usage for the Goodyear blimp is a solecism.

Comment: Thanks, @DanBron, I thought something along those lines about Lycurgus, but by our modern standards many ancient rulers, generals, lawgivers, leaders would be now quite harsh and ruthless, if not outright violent and bloodthirsty. So we should call “infamous” more or less every Homeric hero, Roman emperor, medieval ruler and so on.

Comment: You're right that we could, and modern writers are aware of that, and unabashedly exercise that right when it serves their literary needs. You need an antagonist or anti-hero for your history of the ancient world? Boom! *Let me introduce the **infamous**....* See what I mean?

Comment: The Goodyear Blimp may have been "infamous" in the jaded eye of the cited writer because of its  ubiquity in the air above sporting events.  In decoding language in context, it's important to be on the lookout for the many faces of irony.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess your passages both use *infamous* in the context of **notorious**.

Neither the blimp nor the lawmaker were uniformly good. In fact, every time I saw the blimp, I found it to be a distraction and feared the whole thing exploding.

As for Lycurgus, Wikipedia lists him as responsible for the "military-oriented reformation of Spartan society." I would hardly call this virtuous beyond a doubt.

I admit it's a stretch, but the usage of *infamous* appears to exhibit a pessimistic view of your two examples usually referred to in a positive light. But the authors are taking a minority opinion and apparently drawing a conclusion based on the negatives. As such, neither an oversight nor an alternative usage--just a stretch.

Comment: I agree with your analysis of *infamous* for Lycurgus (as I mentioned in some comments under the question), but I find the defense of that word for the Goodyear Blimp a bit hand-wavey and unconvincing. The GY blimp doesn't broadly suffer from any notoriety or unhappy reputation. If it were the Hindenberg, sure. But I can't see any world in which the description of the GY blimp couldn't be made more accurate by substituting simple "famous" for "infamous". If the author wanted to emphasize the fame, he could have used a less common and therefore more potent synonym, like *celebrated*.

Comment: Having experienced it at multiple sporting events, I like the word *infamous*. But more for comedy's sake, like "Ha, ha--look at the stupid blimp. Now go away." Still, I agree, it's a stretch.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/blimpingainteasy

Answer (score -1):

A person or thing such as the Goodyear Blimp may already be infamous prior to  or by the time of writing for reasons other than the benign events currently being described.

Example 1: The infamous John Wayne Gacy painted clowns.
Painting clowns is not infamous but Gacy's prior and well known murders are.

Example 2: On 10 April 1912, the infamous Titanic successfully sailed from Southampton, England, to Cherbourg, France, and then Queenstown, Ireland, without issue.
At the time of it's sailing the Titanic was famous. Successful sailing did not lead to it's infamy; rather, the Titanic's later sinking after these trips lent to it's infamy at the time of writing.

Comment: But ***is*** there any negative connotation to the Goodyear Blimp? If not, then your contribution doesn’t answer the question.